# Call parameter to function LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am working on a toy language. I want to create a function which takes a function as a parameter which it can call later. In LLVM IR it would look like this:

```
define i8 @foo(i8 ()* %f) {
entry:
  %0 = call i8 %f()
  ret i8 %0
}
```

When I tried to re-create this using the c++ API, I ran into some issues. I created a function type pointer type  `i8 () *` which I set as a parameter to a function type.  Later when I try to call one of the function's arguments (via `func->args()`) I get an error:

```
Assertion failed: (isa<X>(Val) && "cast<Ty>() argument of incompatible type!"), function cast
```

What is this error referring to? How should I go about implementing this?

#### Edits

The function pointer looks like this when I print it (`funcPtr->print(errs())`)

```
i8 ()* %f
```

I don't get an error when loading the pointer but, when I try to print it, I get a bad access exception.

#### Code

```
    auto* funcPtr = namedArgs[name]; // get the function pointer from arguments

    funcPtr->print(errs()); // => `i8 ()* %f`

    func = (Function *)mBuilder.CreateLoad(funcPtr); // no errors

    func->print(errs()); // => Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

Also, here is the final function outputted by my code when the function is not called:

```
define 18 @callme(i8 ()* %f) {
entry:
  ret 18 0
}
```

Comment: There's no code here; it's not even clear whether `i8 ()*` is the type your code creates or the type you want to create. I vote to close.

Comment: Your code looks OK. Try calling `Val->dump()` at the assertion site, maybe that would help.

Comment: @arnt I added some code - does that help?

Comment: @arrowd I updated with the result - any ideas?

Comment: This looks wrong `func = (Function *)mBuilder.CreateLoad(funcPtr);`. Use LLVM RTTI to cast between types: `func = cast<Function>(mBuilder.CreateLoad(funcPtr));`

Comment: @arrowd When I try to cast using llvm, I get the same error where I try to cast. `func = llvm::cast<Function>(loadedFunc);` produces `Assertion failed` (see full error in question). Also thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you still working on this / having the described issues? If so, I can try to look into that.

Comment: Yes, I am. That would be great, thanks @Cherusker.